# How to include webapp_config.txt to Play's dist zip?

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.0, sbt

I've created a prod.conf file which is my configuration file for my production environment. I'd like to ask, is there a way so that whenever I do play dist, the webapp_config.txt file that I've created is included in the zip and placed in the root directory of my web app?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the sbt task `mappings` in `dist`. It is a sequence of tuples (File -> String) that represent which files will be mapped to which paths in the resulting zip file.

In your case the steps to follow are:

1. add `addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-native-packager" % "0.7.1")` to the project/plugins.sbt file
2. `import com.typesafe.sbt.SbtNativePackager._` in your build file
3. add the following to your project settings

   ```
   mappings in (Universal, packageBin) += (baseDirectory.value / "webapp_config.txt") -> "webapp_config.txt"
   ```